namedtuple as argument of a Numba function
I have been struggling to deal efficiently with long lists of arguments of Numba functions. While I initially considered using dictionaries to improve the readability of my code, I realized that namedtuples might be a better alternative. From what I could find online, and based on my tests:

namedtuples are much lighter than dictionaries (in my code, the use of dictionaries decreased performances by about 10%)
namedtuples are more versatile as they can combine different types of variables (int, float, arrays...)
namedtuples also make (at least that is my feeling) the code much easier to read

But... there seems to be a catch : I noticed that the use of namedtuples as arguments of a Numba function makes it impossible to activate the cache=True option. Every time I run my code, it is recompiled which is costly in computation times.
I have the feeling part of the solution lies in an explicit definition of the types of the namedtuples. I found very few posts and details on that topic.
I have two questions :

Is an explicit definition of namedtuples types required for benefiting from the cache=True option in Numba ?
Is there a simple way to do so ?


You can specify the signature like this, but I don't think that will solve the caching problem.

Why not just write a class? There is jitclass for that. IDK if they can be cached though (probably). Dictionary are bad because the indexing is done dynamically which is less safe, slower and also consume more memory.

@JérômeRichard, I just tried to replace my namedtuples by jitclass, it works fine but I still observe the same issue : the code needs to be recompiled every time it runs. Though I believe I may have found a way to solve this with this post : https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4830 (message from lebonez, June 16, 2021).

I found some pieces of information online here and there and I believe it could be of interest to share my conclusions. First of all, the answer to my question :

it does not seem possible to benefit from cache=True when namedtuples are used as arguments of a Numba function.

Now, as suggested in the comments of my initial post, I replaced my namedtuples with a jitclass. It works beautifully and, most importantly, I could not see any loss of performance.
However, if the class is not nested within a Numba function (see this post), passing it as an argument in a Numba function will make it impossible to benefit from cache=True. Luckily, it is pretty straightforward to nest it. By the way, if I am not mistaken, it is not possible to define a namedtuple within a Numba function (to nest it) which might be the reason why I initially observed cache=True was having no effect.
In the end, I created a classes.py file containing :
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, int32, float32, float64, int64    # import the types
from numba.experimental import jitclass

spec_abr = [
    ('E', float64),
    ('K', float64),
    ('sigma_y', float64),
    ('nb_abr_elem', int64),
    ('sharpness', float64),
    ('amplitude', float64),
    ('ep_aub', float64),
    ('ep_aub_ax', float64),
    ('ep_abr', float64),
    ('biseau', float64[:])
]

spec_sim = [
    ('dt', float64),
    ('t99', float64),
    ('mu', float64),
    ('nb_lobe', int64),
    ('largeur_lobe', float64),
    ('hauteur_lobe', float64),
    ('nb_points', int64),
    ('omega', float64)
]

spec_mtx = [
    ('Kl', float64[:,:]),
    ('Ml', float64[:,:]),
    ('Dl', float64[:,:])
]

@jitclass(spec_abr)
class abradable(object):
    def __init__(self, E, K, sigma_y, nb_abr_elem, sharpness, amplitude, ep_aub, ep_aub_ax, ep_abr):
        self.E = E
        self.K = K
        self.sigma_y = sigma_y
        self.nb_abr_elem = nb_abr_elem
        self.sharpness = sharpness
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        self.ep_aub = ep_aub
        self.ep_aub_ax = ep_aub_ax
        self.ep_abr = ep_abr

@jitclass(spec_sim)
class simulation(object):
    def __init__(self, dt, t99, mu, nb_lobe, largeur_lobe, hauteur_lobe, nb_points, omega):
        self.dt = dt
        self.t99 = t99
        self.mu = mu
        self.nb_lobe = nb_lobe
        self.largeur_lobe = largeur_lobe
        self.hauteur_lobe = hauteur_lobe
        self.nb_points = nb_points
        self.omega = omega

@jitclass(spec_mtx)
class matrices(object):
    def __init__(self, Kl, Ml, Dl):
        self.Kl = Kl
        self.Ml = Ml
        self.Dl = Dl

I imported them all where I needed to use them (within the python file where was written my Numba function):
from src.utils.classes import *
...

and I defined my objects accordingly:
# classes
mat_abr = abradable(Eab, Kab, sigma_y, nb_circ_element, sharpness, amplitude, ep_aub, ep_aub_ax, ep_abr)
par_sim = simulation(dt, t99, mu, nb_lobe, width_lobe, height_lobe, nb_points, omega)
matrix = matrices(K, M, D)    

